# Why are shards getting initialized and relocated during bulk insert

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to bulk insert data into a 4 node elasticsearch cluster with 3 data nodes.

Data nodes specs :
16 CPU - 7GB RAM - 500GB SSD

The data is inserted on the non-data node and split on 5 shards and set to have 1 replicate.
There is approximately 250GB of data to insert.

However, after ~40GB of data inserted on each node and one hour of processing while having ~60%CPU and ~30%RAM usage maximum during the whole timespan, some shards get in initialized state:

```
~$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health/osm?level=shards&pretty=true'
{
  "cluster_name" : "elastic_osm",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 4,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 3,
  "active_primary_shards" : 5,
  "active_shards" : 9,
  "relocating_shards" : 1,
  "initializing_shards" : 1,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "indices" : {
    "osm" : {
      "status" : "yellow",
      "number_of_shards" : 5,
      "number_of_replicas" : 1,
      "active_primary_shards" : 5,
      "active_shards" : 9,
      "relocating_shards" : 1,
      "initializing_shards" : 1,
      "unassigned_shards" : 0,
      "shards" : {
        "0" : {
          "status" : "yellow",
          "primary_active" : true,
          "active_shards" : 1,
          "relocating_shards" : 0,
          "initializing_shards" : 1,
          "unassigned_shards" : 0
        },
        "1" : {
          "status" : "green",
          "primary_active" : true,
          "active_shards" : 2,
          "relocating_shards" : 0,
          "initializing_shards" : 0,
          "unassigned_shards" : 0
        },
        "2" : {
          "status" : "green",
          "primary_active" : true,
          "active_shards" : 2,
          "relocating_shards" : 1,
          "initializing_shards" : 0,
          "unassigned_shards" : 0
        },
        "3" : {
          "status" : "green",
          "primary_active" : true,
          "active_shards" : 2,
          "relocating_shards" : 0,
          "initializing_shards" : 0,
          "unassigned_shards" : 0
        },
        "4" : {
          "status" : "green",
          "primary_active" : true,
          "active_shards" : 2,
          "relocating_shards" : 0,
          "initializing_shards" : 0,
          "unassigned_shards" : 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Digging a bit deeper, I found that one node has a problem with the heap space :

```
~$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/osm/_search_shards?pretty=true'
{
  "nodes" : {
    "1DpvDUf7SKywJrBgQqs9eg" : {
      "name" : "elastic-osm-node-1",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/xxx.xxx.x.x:xxxx]",
      "attributes" : {
        "master" : "true"
      }
    },
    "FiBYw-v_QfO3nJQfHflf_w" : {
      "name" : "elastic-osm-node-3",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/xxx.xxx.x.x:x]",
      "attributes" : {
        "master" : "true"
      }
    },
    "ibpt8lGiS6yDJf4e09RN9Q" : {
      "name" : "elastic-osm-node-2",
      "transport_address" : "inet[/xxx.xxx.x.x:xxxx]",
      "attributes" : {
        "master" : "true"
      }
    }
  },
  "shards" : [ [ {
    "state" : "STARTED",
    "primary" : true,
    "node" : "ibpt8lGiS6yDJf4e09RN9Q",
    "relocating_node" : null,
    "shard" : 0,
    "index" : "osm"
  }, {
    "state" : "INITIALIZING",
    "primary" : false,
    "node" : "FiBYw-v_QfO3nJQfHflf_w",
    "relocating_node" : null,
    "shard" : 0,
    "index" : "osm",
    "unassigned_info" : {
      "reason" : "ALLOCATION_FAILED",
      "at" : "2015-10-30T10:42:25.539Z",
      "details" : "shard failure [engine failure, reason [already closed by tragic event]][OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]]"
    }
  } ], [ {
    "state" : "STARTED",
    "primary" : true,
    "node" : "FiBYw-v_QfO3nJQfHflf_w",
    "relocating_node" : null,
    "shard" : 1,
    "index" : "osm"
  }, {
    "state" : "STARTED",
    "primary" : false,
    "node" : "1DpvDUf7SKywJrBgQqs9eg",
    "relocating_node" : null,
    "shard" : 1,
    "index" : "osm"
  } ], [ {
    "state" : "RELOCATING",
    "primary" : false,
    "node" : "FiBYw-v_QfO3nJQfHflf_w",
    "relocating_node" : "1DpvDUf7SKywJrBgQqs9eg",
    "shard" : 2,
    "index" : "osm"
  }, {
    "state" : "STARTED",
    "primary" : true,
    "node" : "ibpt8lGiS6yDJf4e09RN9Q",
    "relocating_node" : null,
    "shard" : 2,
    "index" : "osm"
  }, {
    "state" : "INITIALIZING",
    "primary" : false,
    "node" : "1DpvDUf7SKywJrBgQqs9eg",
    "relocating_node" : "FiBYw-v_QfO3nJQfHflf_w",
    "shard" : 2,
    "index" : "osm"
  } ], [ {
    "state" : "STARTED",
    "primary" : false,
    "node" : "FiBYw-v_QfO3nJQfHflf_w",
    "relocating_node" : null,
    "shard" : 3,
    "index" : "osm"
  }, {
    "state" : "STARTED",
    "primary" : true,
    "node" : "1DpvDUf7SKywJrBgQqs9eg",
    "relocating_node" : null,
    "shard" : 3,
    "index" : "osm"
  } ], [ {
    "state" : "STARTED",
    "primary" : false,
    "node" : "ibpt8lGiS6yDJf4e09RN9Q",
    "relocating_node" : null,
    "shard" : 4,
    "index" : "osm"
  }, {
    "state" : "STARTED",
    "primary" : true,
    "node" : "FiBYw-v_QfO3nJQfHflf_w",
    "relocating_node" : null,
    "shard" : 4,
    "index" : "osm"
  } ] ]
}
```

However the ES_HEAP_SIZE set on the server is half of the ram :

```
~$ echo $ES_HEAP_SIZE
7233.0m
```

and the usage is only 5g:

```
~$ free -g
             total       used
Mem:            14          5
```

and if I wait a bit more the node completely leaves the cluster and all the replicas get in initialized state which makes my insertion fail and stop :

```
{
    "state" : "INITIALIZING",
    "primary" : false,
    "node" : "ibpt8lGiS6yDJf4e09RN9Q",
    "relocating_node" : null,
    "shard" : 3,
    "index" : "osm",
    "unassigned_info" : {
      "reason" : "NODE_LEFT",
      "at" : "2015-10-30T10:53:32.044Z",
      "details" : "node_left[FiBYw-v_QfO3nJQfHflf_w]"
    }
```

Conf : In order to speed up the insert I use those parameters on the data nodes elasticsearch configuration

refresh_interval : -1,
threadpool.bulk.size: 16,
threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 1000

Why does this happen ? And how can I fix this and get my bulk insert to succeed?
Do I need more than 50% of the RAM for the maximum heap size?

EDIT : Since it's not good to tweak the elasticsearch parameters I removed the threadpool parameters and it worked but very slowly. Elasticsearch is not designed to ingest too much data too fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these settings:

```
threadpool.bulk.size: 16
threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 1000
```

Those setting's defaults should be good enough for not overloading the cluster.

And make sure you size properly your bulk indexing process, following the instructions [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bulk.html#_how_big_is_too_big). Depending on the cluster/data the bulk needs to have a certain size. You can't use whatever values you want for those hoping to ingest as much as possible. Every cluster has limitations and you should test yours.

Comment: The size of the bulk requests are 5000 and are made by 30 workers. This cluster seems to be able to ingest the data at this rate, without those parameters and when I reduce the number of workers inserting data, the CPU of my data nodes barely reach 10%. Moreover then RAM usage doesn't change that much during the process at full rate. Doesn't that mean that the cluster is able to ingest data at that rate? Shouldn't the cluster be able to go to at least 60% of the CPU?

Comment: It seems it is not, since nodes are dropping from the cluster and the heap usage is not great (haven't seen proof of heap problems, but you mentioned it). Grep your nodes' logs for `[gc][old]` or `[gc][young]`. Do you have such entries?

Comment: Just checked, no entry on all of the nodes. I know it's not recommended to tweak ES parameters but aren't ingestion capacities supposed to scale with the cluster?

Comment: Yes, that's true. Weird that you don't have those entries. Since you mentioned heap problems I would have expected that your bulk process altered (in a bad way) the garbage collection processes of Java.

Comment: yes, that could be expected. I only get this warning hundreds of times when the node disconnected and that's all : [2015-10-30 [elastic-osm-node-2] failed to perform indices:data/write/bulk[s] on remote replica [elastic-osm-node-1][1DpvDUf7SKywJrBgQqs9eg][elastic-osm-node-1.l][inet[xxxxxx]]{master=true}[osm][2] org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [elastic-osm-node-1][inet[/xxxxxxx]][indices:data/write/bulk[s][r]] disconnected ....

Comment: The main question is **why the node disconnected?**. Can you share the log file of `elastic-osm-node-1` node from the time you had the problem?